# Laravel reversed insert pivot table query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am making an app, but when I'm inserting some relatisonship data, the generated query is inversed and I dont'k now why.

```
$last_fab->medidas()->attach(
    $last_medida->id_medida, ["medida" => $newPedidos[$i]["medidas_fab"][$j]["meters"]]
);
```

$last_fab is an insance of Fabricacion, and Fabricacion has this relationship whit Medidas:

```
public function medidas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Medida", "fabricacion_medidas", "id_medida", "id_fabricacion")->withPivot("medida");
}
```

$last_medida is an instance of Medida, and Medida has this relationship whith Fabricacion:

```
public function fabricaciones() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Fabricacion", "fabricacion_medidas", "id_fabricacion", "id_medida")->withPivot("medida");
}
```

There is the Migration code:

```
//fabricacion
Schema::create("fabricacion", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";

    $table->increments("id_fabricacion");
    $table->integer("id_order");
    $table->integer("id_megacart")->nullable();
    $table->string("reference");
    $table->string("name");
    $table->float("width");
    $table->float("height");
    $table->float("length");
    $table->date("date_update");
    $table->integer("id_categoria")->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer("id_ubicacion")->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer("id_incidencia")->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer("estado")->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
});

//medidas
Schema::create("medidas", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";

    $table->increments("id_medida");
    $table->string("nom_medida")->nullable();
});

//fabricacion_medidas
Schema::create("fabricacion_medidas", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";

    $table->integer("id_fabricacion")->unsigned();
    $table->integer("id_medida")->unsigned();
    $table->integer("medida");
});

Schema::table("fabricacion_medidas", function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('id_fabricacion')->references('id_fabricacion')->on('fabricacion');
    $table->foreign('id_medida')->references('id_medida')->on('medidas');
});
```

And here the error it shows to me:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
 a foreign key constraint fails (`asensiapp`.`fabricacion_medidas`, CONSTRAINT 
`fabricacion_medidas_id_medida_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_medida`) 
REFERENCES `medidas` (`id_medida`)) (SQL: insert into `fabricacion_medidas`
 (`id_fabricacion`, `id_medida`, `medida`) values (1, 10, 1.343))
```

And sometimes is the same error but it refers to id_fabricaccion instead of id_medida.
Where in values, 10 is the id_fabricacion, and 1 is the id_medida. So I don't know why is not in the correct position.

Comment: Is there a record in the `medidas` table with id 10? Because your error says it's missing.

Comment: No, that's the problem, I just added a line in the post: id_fabricacion and id_medida have the position changed, In theory the order should be fine. But in my case is altered

Comment: Are you trying to update the pivot table or create a new record?

Comment: I am creating a new record. Well, first I create a new Fabrication, then a new Medida, finally I create a new record in the pivot table where id_fabricacion is the new inserted Fabricacion, id_medida is the new inserted Medida and medida is other table row

Comment: I got the problem! Answer is below. May I ask why you're programming in Spanish? Seems weird to me, because I never program in my native language!

Comment: I am programming in both, I like to program in english too, but my partner wants some things in spanish haha

Comment: Ah okay! I hope you'll be able to convince him one day, because code is way more readable in English if you ask me! ;) And btw, if you like my answer, don't forget to upvote! Upvoting is the core mechanism of this website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reversed the relationships in your models:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('[ExternalClass]', '[table]', '[CurrentClassId]', '[ExternalClassId]');
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

So your `Fabricacion` becomes

```
public function medidas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Medida", "fabricacion_medidas", "id_fabricacion", "id_medida")->withPivot("medida");
}
```

And your `Medidas` becomes

```
public function fabricaciones() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Fabricacion", "fabricacion_medidas", "id_medida", "id_fabricacion")->withPivot("medida");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's right. I thought in the relationships the foreign key was the model relation key and te related key was the local key. Many thanks ^^